# Filter Pandas Dataframe columns with a complex condition generated by a predicate function (defined on columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to filter out pandas dataframe columns with a condition defined on its columns with a predicate function, for example (generally it may be much more sophisticated with rather complex dependencies between different elements of the series):

```
def detect_jumps(data, jump_factor=5):
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        if data[i] - data[i - 1] > jump_factor:
            return True
    return False
```

on a dataframe `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    {'A': '10', 'B': '10', 'C': '100', 'D': '100', 'E': '0', },
    {'A': '15', 'B': '16', 'C': '105', 'D': '104', 'E': '10', },
    {'A': '20', 'B': '20', 'C': '110', 'D': '110', 'E': '11', },
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

i.e.

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   10  10  100 100 0
1   15  16  105 104 10
2   20  20  110 110 11
```

It should only filter out columns **B** (col[1] - col[0] == 6 > 5) and **D** (col[2] - col[1] == 6 > 5)

or predicate `detect_jumps(data, 9)` and in this case it should only filter out column **E** (col[1] - col[0] == 10 > 9)

Are there any ways to use such functions as a condition for filtering?

Comment: Columns A-D have different threshold than Column E?  Or if any column difference exceed 6 eliminate that column?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a custom function, use vectorial operations:

```
df2 = df.loc[:, ~df.astype(int).diff().gt(5).any()]
```

output:

```
    A    C
0  10  100
1  15  105
2  20  110
```

Nevertheless, using your function:

```
df2 = df.loc[:, [not detect_jumps(c) for label, c in df.astype(int).items()]]

# OR
df2 = df[[label for label, c in df.astype(int).items() if not detect_jumps(c)]]
```